# unix & gnu/linux distributions: possible locations for 'which' command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, csh

Would like to reference the full path to the **which** command as an *improvement* to some shell scripts. Is anyone aware of a standard location for some unix gnu/linux distribution **BESIDES** /usr/bin/which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which is not a standard part of linux systems. It's not present in Linux Standard Base 4.1, and not present in Single Unix Specification Version 4/POSIX 2008:

- http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/toccommand.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html

So the only formal answer for the question is that which has no reliable location in the file system.

For the practical solution: which should always be available in the default search path directories. So the best practical answer: run which from your script without a hard coded path. [Edit: any solution with a set of hard coded paths is worse than using the default search paths].

Comment: This response is certainly the most educating. You haven't cited any counter examples.Using the standard search path doesn't work for users like me who create a bash function to supercede /usr/bin/which (to incorporate aliases and functions).

Comment: Slackware 14.0 installs which in /bin. http://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware-current&p=which-2.20-i486-1.txz&f

Comment: About bash functions: bash supports aliasing which and calling it while searching paths, as can be seen in this example: http://pastebin.com/VzSZ14qk

Comment: Yes, bash supports aliasing which, hence the need to code the full path to the *original*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
which -a which
```

The `-a` flag lists all locations for the supplied arguments (opposed to returning  the pathnames  of the files or links which would be executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given as command in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.)

Comment: As with another answer, this sidesteps the problem. Really like to hardcode a solution that works, not examine the situation at run time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to hard-code these paths in? The  solution above will guarantee it works at run-time, while hard-coding it in does not.

Comment: The solution above won't guarantee it will run. It will run some "which" and it might return a list. It does not help identify the which you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

you can try :

```
whereis which
```

`whereis` locates the binary, source for a command